# Get the web service end point URL dynamically

Tags: android, web-services, dynamic, push-notification, google-cloud-endpoints

We are developing an Android application. For back end services we have used REST API. We have different API methods like Authenticate, Send Info.

To authenticate the user we need the web service end point URL at very first time.

The web service end point will change from time to time like Stage URL, Production URL and all. How our mobile app will know this dynamically.

One way is by using Push notification we can send the Dynamic web service end point to the device.

Is there any other way, like, can we update in Cloud system and get it from our application?

I hear about Google Cloud End point. Is good to use for this to get the base URL only?

Comment: Push notification isn't reliable solution. It can arrive at any time or be lost in the process (e.g. when device is turned off for too long). I would go with some static file hosted in permanent location which would point to your end point and check for changes periodically. This solution is similar to how torrent trackers work.

Comment: we are using PubNub for push notification. basically it will work like socket connection between device and pubnub server then between pubnub server and our web server. Berfore making authentication api call we can get the base URL using that. Correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To change your different endpoint from staging or production is a pretty significant change, and shouldn't require such an over-engineered system of notifications. Simply deploy a "staging" version of your app for developers that connects to the staging API environment.

Comment: Even after in Production if I want to change the URL will lead to built a new APK by Hard Coding that Changed URL. We dont have to build every time new apk. The existing APK should behave accordingly.

Comment: Alright so have your endpoint value stored in a data store of some kind (MySQL, Datastore, Cloud SQL, etc.) and retrieve that URL when you want to make a request, keeping it cached in device local storage. Whenever the app starts up, make a request to that location to check if the endpoints changed.

Finally, if you really want to be super responsive about it, yes, you can use some kind of push notification or pub/sub service. To be super robust, you can combine all these methods. 

Seems as though you answered your own question!

Comment: Not to mention, the URL shouldn't really be changing that often. Once again, I think this is over-engineering. Do you not intend to host a stable domain name, with a stable route to your API?

Comment: Yes as you said we need to have at-least one static URL to get the dynamically changed URL. Thanks for your ans.